# Inverse Fast Fourier Transform Implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, math, fft

I'm trying to program a FFT algorithm in Python and I've got the initial transform working. It takes in a polynomial in vector form and spits out the evaluation of that vector at the complex roots of unity. The issue arises in my Inverse FFT. This is supposed to take in the evaluation of a function at the complex roots and return the polynomial that passes through those points. This second half is nearly identical to the first, but it uses the inverse of the complex roots. The output of this is scaled by the number of input points, so each coefficient is divided by that number.

My code looks like:

```py
import math

from cmath import sqrt


def getNthRoots(n):
    # Determines how many roots are needed. Only works for powers of two.

    targetLength = math.pow(2, math.ceil(math.log(n, 2)))
    newOutput = [1.0 + 0j]

    # Starting with just 1, it takes the sqrt of each term and appends it. Then it appends a negative copy of the list.

    while len(newOutput) < targetLength:
        previous = newOutput
        newOutput = []

        for item in range(len(previous)):
            newOutput.append(sqrt(previous[item]))

        for item in range(len(newOutput)):
            newOutput.append(newOutput[item] * -1)

    return newOutput
```

This works excellently.

```py
def FFT(inputList, rootsOfUnity):
    # End case for the loop

    if len(inputList) == 1:
        return [inputList[0]]

    # Splits the input list into two parts, one even and one odd

    evenList = [inputList[2 * x] for x in range((len(inputList) // 2))]

    oddList = [inputList[(2 * x) + 1] for x in range(len(inputList) // 2)]

    # Takes the "square" of the roots of unity. This is the same as just taking every other entry.

    newRootsOfU = [rootsOfUnity[2 * x] for x in range((len(rootsOfUnity) // 2))]

    # Calls itself with the even and odd halves and the shortened roots of unity

    evenTransform = FFT(evenList, newRootsOfU)

    oddTransform = FFT(oddList, newRootsOfU)

    outputs = []

    # Calculates the output for each root of unity

    for x in range(len(rootsOfUnity)):
        outputs.append(evenTransform[x % (int(len(rootsOfUnity) / 2))] + rootsOfUnity[x] * oddTransform[
            x % (int(len(rootsOfUnity) / 2))])

    return outputs

PolyVec1 = [1, 5, 3, 2]

# addZeros just attaches zeros until the length of the list is a power of two
PolyVec1 = addZeros(PolyVec1)

# Converts PolyVec1 into point form
rootsOfUnity = getNthRoots(len(PolyVec1))

PolyPoint1 = FFT(PolyVec1, rootsOfUnity)
toBeInverted = getNthRoots(len(PolyVec1))
InvertedRoots = [1 / i for i in toBeInverted]
reversedFFT1 = FFT(PolyPoint1, InvertedRoots)
print(reversedFFT1)
reversedFFT1Final = [abs(i) / len(reversedFFT1) for i in reversedFFT1]
print(reversedFFT1Final)
```

This code works fine for converting a polynomial into a series of points. However, when I try and use it to find the inverse it doesn't work for polynomials of a degree greater than 3.

Any idea why?

Edit:

I've had some new insights. The output for any polynomial

[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]

is

[a, y, c, z, e, y, g, z]

a, c, e, and g are all consistently interpolated, but b, d, f, and h are not. b and f are replaced by the same value and d and h are replaced by a different value. As long as b and f are identical and d and h are identical, the output will be correct.

Edit:

More insight. It has something to do with complex numbers. No matter the input, a, c, e, g always have no complex component and when b and f or d and h are identical, the output has no complex component. When there is a complex component, the output is incorrect.

Comment: Format your code properly please

Comment: And what is your question now?

Comment: *...The issue arises in my Inverse FFT...* But what is the issue?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I suppose my questions is why is this behavior emerging? What part of the code is causing these patterns in incorrect answers?